# Is it possible to declare app twice (reactJS)

Tags: reactjs

is it possible to declare app in server.js twice? I was trying to code a contact form, but now I want to include it into an existing page. In the server.js file I have already declared app:

```
const app = next({ dev })
```

It is sending an email when I type node.js but I want to send when I press submit below my contact form.

In my other application, I have a contact form, but there is

```
const app = express()
```

declared.

I know, that I can't declare it twice with

```
const app = next({ dev })
const app =express()
```

but is it possible to do it in another way? I am searching for a few days but I'm not finding anything, that helps me.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with express instead of reactjs?

Comment: I have two applications: One normal site and a site with a contact form with nodemailer. In the server.js from the nodemailer application is app=express() declared. But I want to put these two applications together. But I can't declare app=express() in the server.js from the first application because app is already declared.

Answer (score 0):

**Base Problem**

Your question basically boils down to how scope in JS is working and probably on how modules and compilers in webpack work.

**Understanding**

If you use modules, you will export the variables you need anyway and the compiler creates [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) so you can use the same variable name across the project as often as you wish.

```
(function () { // open IIFE
    const app = express() // inside IIFE
}()); // close IIFE and declare app again in other module without interference
```